# Google Cloud Endpoints : Start a servlet from @ApiMethod

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

The way I currently handle image uploads to the blobstore is to have an @ApiMethod like

```
@ApiMethod( name = "getUploadUrl",
            path = "/images/uploadurl",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET )

public UploadUrl getUploadUrl( HttpServletRequest request ) throws UnauthorizedException
{
    authenticateRequest( request );
    return new UploadUrl( blobstoreService.createUploadUrl( "/image" ) );
}
```

A client sends a first request to this method which gives him an URL on which he can send his image alongwith the name he should use for the upload.

The client nows send a second request containing the actual image encoded as form-data to this URL and upon successful upload to the blobstore, I do my post processing in the servlet mapped to "/image" path

Now, I want the upload operation to be a singe request from client perspective. I understand that this will involve calling the `UploadBlobServlet` programatically from my @ApiMethod. So referred to the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-2634/gcozl/index.html) and changed my @ApiMethod as

```
@ApiMethod( name = "uploadImage",
            path = "/images/upload",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST )

public void uploadImage( ServletContext context, HttpServletRequest request ) throws UnauthorizedException
{
    authenticateRequest( request );
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher( blobstoreService.createUploadUrl( "/image" ) );
    dispatcher.forward( request, ??? );
}
```

The trouble is, I can [inject the ServletContext and the HttpServletRequest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types) in my method, but not `HttpServletResponse`, which `dispatcher.forward()` needs (obviously).

So then, what is the proper way to start a servlet from an endpoints @ApiMethod?